# How do I remove certain fields from the forum edit my profile page?

Tags: bbpress

My users are able to click on their forum profile and edit things like their password and picture but I don't want some fields to appear. How can I get rid of: First Name, Last Name, Contact Info, Website, Blog Role and Forum Role?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I don't really know where to start and I don't want to damage any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to edit the `form-user-edit.php` template located in `/templates/default/bbpress/` and remove the fields you do not want your users to be able to edit.

Make sure that you don't edit bbPress core files and copy the template to your themes `/bbpress` folder as outlined in the codex http://codex.bbpress.org/theme-compatibility/